# Can I create a WordPress custom table with PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

I have a WooCommerce website where I sell ticket for events.
Each time a user buy a ticket, he receives by mail a unique QR code (his ticket).

Now, I have to create a special application to manage entries in the event. Stakeholders asked to have the date and hour of entries of each ticket.
To do so, I would like to create a custom table having primary key (orderId, productId, entryId) and a field "timestamp".

My question is: can I naively create a table in the database with PhpMyAdmin without having any trouble ?

Comment: You can do that

Comment: Thanks. For my data, do you recommend that I create another table and query manually, or add data in the metadata via the wordpress api?

Answer (score 0):

You can create using ACF - Advanced Custom Fields

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

You have more information for ACF on WooCommerce here.

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-with-woocommerce/